# Javascript / JSON how to access value of array

Tags: javascript

I have following json array. I want to access the value of `revenue` for all of them.

```
data = [
    {"year": 2017, "revenue": 1000, "cost": 500},
    {"year": 2016, "revenue": 1500, "cost": 900},
    {"year": 2015, "revenue": 900, "cost": 300}
]
```

I can get `data[0].revenue`. But it only give me access to one year. How can I access them all? I'm really new to javascript.

Comment: `data.forEach(yearObject => console.log(yearObject.revenue));`

Comment: Do enough research before asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  var record=data[i];
  console.log(record.year, record.revenue, record.cost);
}
```